# Erro na query do postgre: ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE"

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estava trabalhando com mysql neste projeto e a query funcionava normalmente. No momento, estou migrando para postgresql. Contudo, a query deixou de funcionar e me retorna o seguinte erro:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE"

**Meu código**

```
@Query(value = "SELECT b.nome FROM escala a INNER JOIN medico b " 
                +"INNER JOIN ordem c ON c.medico_crm = b.crm AND a.id = c.escala_id " 
                +"WHERE month(a.data) = :mes AND year(a.data) = :ano AND "
                + "b.categoria = :categoria group by b.nome", nativeQuery=true)
Set<String> getNomeMedicos(@Param("mes") int mes, @Param("ano") int ano, @Param("categoria") String categoria);
```

Comment: Acho que faltou o "on" da 'medico'.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver. Vou explicar para quem tiver o mesmo problema. Não havia erro de syntax, mas sim a estrutura da query estava errado. Acima, note que o select é referente a tabela medico b, contudo o from é da tabela escala a.
Para ficar mais claro, segue o código corrigido:

```sql
SELECT a.nome from medico a INNER JOIN ordem b INNER JOIN escala c ON a.crm = b.medico_crm AND b.escala_id = c.id 
WHERE day(c.data) = :dia AND month(c.data) = :mes AND year(c.data) = :ano AND c.turno = :turno;
```

Answer (score 0):

Os comandos `Month` e `Year` são operadores do MySQL

O Postgres possui um comando chamado

> EXTRACT(oQue FROM deQuem)

Por tanto, creio que seu código deva ficar assim:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT b.nome FROM escala a INNER JOIN medico b " 
            +"INNER JOIN ordem c ON c.medico_crm = b.crm AND a.id = c.escala_id " 
            +"WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM a.data) = :mes AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM a.data) = :ano AND "
            + "b.categoria = :categoria group by b.nome", nativeQuery=true)
Set<String> getNomeMedicos(@Param("mes") int mes, @Param("ano") int ano, @Param("categoria") String categoria);
```

Esse comando é responsável por obter valores de datas onde o primeiro parâmetro será o que você deseja obter e o segundo de onde você deseja obter.
Acima ilustrei o primeiro parâmetro o chamando de `oQue` e o segundo de `deQuem`.

Comment: Você tem razão. Mas este problema eu encontrei depois de resolver o problemas que expus aqui. Acabei descobrindo isso que você explicou. Mesmo assim, muito obrigado pela atenção!